# Laravel getClientOriginalName inside foreach loop

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, laravel-5.1

I cannot call this method

```
getClientOriginalName
```

inside this loop

```
        foreach ($request->file('images', []) as $scenesImagesData) {
            $scenes_images = new ScenesImages($scenesImagesData);
            $scenes_images->product()->associate($product);
            $fileName  = $scenesImagesData->getClientOriginalName();
            $filePath  = $targetPath . '\\' . $fileName;
            $scenes_images->save();
        }
```

I get following error:

```
Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on a non-object
```

If I dd($scenesImagesData) I get this:

```
array:1 [▼
  "scenes_images" => UploadedFile {#30 ▼
    -test: false
    -originalName: "dog.jpg"
    -mimeType: "image/jpeg"
    -size: 434516
    -error: 0
  }
]
```

Which was the file I picked.

Thus I do have a

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

in my form.

If I `print_r($scenesImagesData);`

I get following:

> Array ( [scenes_images] =>
>   Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile Object (
>   [test:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] =>
>   [originalName:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private]
>   => dog.jpg [mimeType:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private]
>   => image/jpeg [size:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] =>
>   434516
>   [error:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] =>
>   0 [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => C:\xampp\tmp\php786B.tmp
>   [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => php786B.tmp ) )

Comment: Try   `$fileName  = $scenesImagesData['scenes_images']->getClientOriginalName();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you have an object inside an array, so try this:

```
$name = $scenesImagesData['scenes_images']->getClientOriginalName();
```

Comment: Thanks but I get this Call to a member function get() on a non-object

Comment: Try updated code. You have an instance of `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile Object` in an array, so this should work.

Comment: nice worked, do you know how to so to say add it to my save()

Comment: As usual, something like `$scenes_images->nameOfTheFieldInDB = $scenesImagesData['scenes_images']->getClientOriginalName();`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$scenesImagesData["scenes_images"]->UploadedFile()->originalName
```

or

```
$scenesImagesData["scenes_images"]->getClientOriginalName();
```

one of them or both should work.

Comment: if I dd($scenesImagesData['originalName']); I get an Undefined index: originalName

Comment: let me know what print_r($scenesImagesData); showing plz